# Rails　Controller　１対多関係にあるテーブルのカラムの値を取り出し、合算したものをViewで表示させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

【実現したい事】
①１対多の関係にあるテーブルがあり、子関係にあるテーブルのカラムの値を取り出したい
②取り出したものを合算してViewで表示させたい（＝赤枠部分の合計練習時間を表示させたい）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【環境】　※未経験からエンジニア転職を目指してオリジナルアプリを開発中の者です（学習期間約2ヶ月程度）。
・Ruby：2.6.5
・Rails:5.2.4.3
・DB設計 ※詳細は下記コード
親：Recordテーブル
子：Practiceテーブル

【試した事】
①Controllerのindexアクションに、total_practice_timeという新しい変数を宣言し、子レコード（Practiceテーブル）モデルの配列「:practices」を代入させる

②次の処理で、ブロック引数|total|を定めて、格納されているpractice_timeの値を全て足し算したものを結果として取り出す処理をする

しかし、「Syntax error」と出ており、何をどう直すべきか分からないため、ご意見・アドバイスを頂戴できますと幸いです。

**records_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @records = current_user.records.includes(:practices).page(params[:page]).per(8)

    total_practice_time = Record.includes(:practices)
      total_practice_time.each do |total|
        total.sum(:practice_time)
      end
    end
```

**index.html.slim**

```
h1 練習記録一覧
.container
  .row
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = form_with model: @record do |f|
          = f.date_field :training_date

table.table-hover.table-respnsive
  thead
    tr
      th 練習日
      th 登録日時
      th 総練習時間
      th
      th
  tbody
    - @records.each do |record|
      - record.practices.each do |practice|
        tr
          td= link_to record.training_date, record_path(record)
          td= record.created_at
          td= total
          / td= practice.practice_time
          td
            = link_to '編集する', edit_record_path(record), class: 'btn btn-primary mr-3'
            = link_to '削除する', record_path(record), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "練習記録を削除します。よろしいですか？" }, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

【コード】

**Recordモデル**

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  validates :learning_point, presence: true
  validates :training_date, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :practices, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :practices
end
```

**Practiceモデル**

```
class Practice < ApplicationRecord
  validates :practice_item, presence: true
  validates :practice_time, presence: true
  belongs_to :record
end
```

**shema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_05_25_064157) do

  create_table "records", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "user_id"
    t.text "learning_point"
    t.date "training_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "practices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "practice_item"
    t.integer "practice_time"
    t.bigint "record_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["record_id"], name: "index_practices_on_record_id"
  end
```

Comment: 次質問なさるときに参考にしていただきたいのですが、エラーメッセージは省略するのではなくて全部あると嬉しいです。たとえば今回の場合は Syntax Error、つまりプログラムの構文のエラーがプログラムのどこで起きていたのかがエラーメッセージに書かれています。この情報が無い場合、回答者はプログラムを全部丁寧に読んで Syntax Error を見つけないといけません。よろしくお願いします<(\_ \_)>

Comment: nekketsuuuさん
おはようございます。アドバイスいただきありがとうございます。Syntax Errorについては、includesブロックのところで1つ多くendを入れてしまっており、endを消去すると解決しました。

今後ご質問させていただく際は、Logとエラーメッセージ全部記述するようにいたします。貴重な時間を割いてアドバイスいただきありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

こんばんは。

ざっと質問を読ませていただきました。
やりたいこととしては、子モデルであるpracticeのpractice_time合計を出し、recordの一覧に並べて表示したいということかなと思いました。
とすると、view側index.html.slimで以下のような書き方ができるのではと思いますが、いかがでしょうか？

```
  tbody
    - @records.each do |record|
      tr
        td= link_to record.training_date, record_path(record)
        td= record.created_at
        td= record.practices.sum(:practice_time)
```

他にもいろいろ実現方法はあると思いますが、上記がある程度シンプルかなと。
もしやりたいことと異なっていたらすみません！

Comment: ＞やりたいこととしては、子モデルであるpracticeのpractice_time合計を出し、recordの一覧に並べて表示したいということかなと思いました。
→はい、おっしゃる通りです！各Recordのidごとに格納されている、Practice（子モデル）のPractice＿timeの値の合計を一覧表示するということです！

今気づいたのですが、肝心のpractice_timeを記述するフォームが、複数格納できるよう記述できていなかったので、そこを実装したうえで、仰って頂いた方法で実装してみます！ありがとうございます！！

そんな簡単な方法で（.sumと、小モデルの属性をハッシュで書く）実装できるとは、、、というのが正直な感想です。

Answer (score 1):

Syntax Error 自体はおそらく下の部分で起きています。一見ブロックを始めているように見えますが、`Record.includes(:practices)` だけではブロックが始まりません。`do ... end` または `{ ... }` が必要です。

```
total_practice_time = Record.includes(:practices)
  total_practice_time.each do |total|
    total.sum(:practice_time)
  end
end
```

また、中にある `total_practice_time.each` というのも怪しそうです。

合計を計算したいのであれば、モデルで sum を取るのがシンプルかなと思います。Record モデルに下のようにメソッドを作ってビューで参照する形です。またこのくらい簡潔であれば [Awakichi さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/67736/19110)のようにビューで計算してしまっても良さそうです。

```
def total_practice_time
  practices.sum(:practice_time)
end
```

※ただしこれは N+1 クエリなことに注意してください。データ量によっては直す必要があります。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん
ご丁寧に回答いただきありがとうございます。
最初のSyntaxは、仰る通りの部分でエラーになっておりまして、修正したら「No method Error 」となりました。


モデルでsumを取るやり方、もしくはViewで直接計算させるやり方、どちらもやってみます！